# Effective way to clear again the text box

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way that when I search again, I will not have a button that will clear it? the code will just be in the search button. I'm not really familiar with vb.net. I just know how to clear again in list view without having any button to clear it.. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
    If txtsearch.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Pls enter valid values", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else
        searchrecord("SELECT * FROM Clothes where Size like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' order by Size")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Insert [**`ListView.Items.Clear()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) before searching?

Comment: or, if you want to clear the contents of the textbox: `txtSearch.Text = ""`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
                If txtsearch.Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox("Pls enter valid values", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                Else
                    ListViewName.Items.Clear() 'just clear the list view before the query again
                    searchrecord("SELECT * FROM Clothes where Size like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' order by Size")

                End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnsearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
    If txtsearch.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Pls enter valid values", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Else
        searchrecord("SELECT * FROM Clothes where Size like '%" &  txtsearch.Text & "%' order by Size")
        txtsearch.Text = "" '<-- adding this
    End If
End Sub
```